# awk to remove 5th column from N column with fixed delimiter

Tags: awk

1. I have file with Nth columns
2. I want to remove the 5th column from last of Nth columns
3. Delimiter is "|"

I tested with simple example as shown below:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8" | nawk -F\| '{print $(NF-4)}'
4
```

Expecting result:

```
1|2|3|5|6|7|8
```

How should I change my command to get the desired output?

Comment: what do you mean with _remove the 5th from the last column_? Provide a [mcve] so it is more clear.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense as of now.

Comment: Think he means, number of columns is not fixed and needs to remove the 5th column from the last! :) @sjsam

Comment: @Inian : I see. thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not guessing at your requirements and have something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: @Ed/sjsam, what I meant is what Inian has correctly 'guessed' =>  "Think he means, number of columns is not fixed and needs to remove the 5th column from the last! :"

Comment: Great! Now [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not guessing at your requirements and have something we can test a potential solution against. See [ask].

Comment: @Ed, please find revised question with testable sample input and expecting output which is yet to achieve.  The awk command I used is to run in Solaris.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use something like this:

```
sed -E 's/\|[^|]*((\|[^|]*){4})$/\1/'
```

This matches a pipe character `\|` followed by any number of non-pipe characters `[^|]*`, then captures 4 more of the same pattern `((\|[^|]*){4})`. The `$` at the end matches the end of the line. The first part of the match (i.e. the fifth field from the end) is dropped.

Testing it out:

```
$ sed -E 's/\|[^|]*((\|[^|]*){4})$/\1/' <<<"1|2|3|4|5|6|7"
1|2|4|5|6|7
```

You could achieve the same thing using GNU awk with `gensub` but I think that sed is the right tool for the job in this case.

If your version of sed doesn't support extended regex syntax with `-E`, you can modify it slightly:

```
sed 's/|[^|]*\(\(|[^|]*\)\{4\}\)$/\1/'
```

In basic mode, pipes are interpreted literally but parentheses for capture groups and curly brcneed to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it works on my case.  Thanks very much and I learned.

Comment: what about to execute the above 'sed' command in Solaris? I tried but it shown illegal argument with '-E'.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks. I tested and got different output: bash-3.2$ sed 's/|[^|]*\(\(|[^|]*\)\{4\}\)$/\1/' <<<"1|2|3|4|5|6|7"
1|2|3|4|5|6|7

Answer (score 1):

**AWK** is your friend :

---

**Sample Input**

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|A
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|F|E|D|O|R|Q|U|I
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|E|O|Q
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|X
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L
```

**Script**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"}
      {$(NF-5)="";sub(/\|\|/,"|");print}' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
A|B|C|E|F|G|H|I
A|B|C|D|F|G|H|I|A
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|F|E|O|R|Q|U|I
A|B|C|D|E|F|H|I|E|O|Q
A|B|C|D|F|G|H|I|X
A|B|C|D|E|F|H|I|J|K|L
```

**What we did here**

1. As you are aware awk's has special variables to store each field in the record, which ranges from `$1`,`$2` upto `$(NF)`
2. To exclude the 5th from the last column is as simple as

   - Emptying the colume ie `$(NF-5)=""`
   - Removing from the record, the consecutive `|` formed by the above step ie do 
     `sub(/\|\|/,"|")`

Comment: If you're not going to use capture groups, you may as well just use plain `sub` to perform the substitution and then print the line.

Comment: @TomFenech : Well yes and that would make the solution more portable  I guess. :) Thankyou.

Comment: You don't need to specify `,$0` on the `sub()` as that's the default but more importantly this will fail if/when a field before the one you're trying to delete is empty.

Comment: @EdMorton : See the point. Waiting for the op to respond to your comment.

Comment: @sjsam/Ed, below is what I slightly modified from the given and tested as expected in my Solaris environment:  echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | nawk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {$(NF-4)="!";print}' | sed 's/|!//'
1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9    Thanks.

Comment: @Fehan : Glad it worked. You may accept any of the answers if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative, using @sjsam's input file

```
$ rev file | cut -d'|' --complement -f6 | rev 

A|B|C|E|F|G|H|I
A|B|C|D|F|G|H|I|A
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|F|E|O|R|Q|U|I
A|B|C|D|E|F|H|I|E|O|Q
A|B|C|D|F|G|H|I|X
A|B|C|D|E|F|H|I|J|K|L
```

not sure you want the 5'th from the last or 6th.  But it's easy to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and guidance.

Below is what I tested:

bash-3.2$ echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | nawk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {$(NF-4)="!";print}' | sed 's/|!//'

Output: 1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9

Further tested on the file that I have extracted from system and so it worked fine.